# Update varchar2 SQL using same data plus new data

Tags: sql, oracle

For example.
I have a table which is defined as such:

```
PEOPLE table:
id number;
name varchar2;
```

Which contains rows like:

```
Id    Name
1     John
2     Jim
```

I using this following query for updation:

```
UPDATE PEOPLE SET NAME = name + ' Bravo' where id = 1;
```

This is the output I expect:

```
name//john Bravo
```

Isn't possible?

Comment: I'd use UPDATE people SET name=CONCAT(name, " Bravo") WHERE id=1;

Comment: Added oracle tag.  `varchar2` is an Oracle construct.

Comment: really bad forum. yes, maybe i not tag correctly but the reputation point been deduct without any comment or help , the vote down and up system should be improve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string concatenation operator in SQL is `||`

```
UPDATE PEOPLE 
    SET NAME = name || ' Bravo' 
where id = 1;
```

You mention `varchar2`, so I assume you are using Oracle.

Please see the manual for details: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/operators003.htm#SQLRF51158